# Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported how can i fix it

Tags: php

i have this code

```
$read = preg_replace(array('/LANG\[([0-9]*?)\]/e','/URL\[([0-9]*?)\]/e'),array('get_words(\\1)','url(\\1)'),$read);
```

how to fix it using  preg_replace_callback

Comment: You probably need `preg_replace_callback_array`, example #1 here looks like the one you need: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array.php

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you to remove the `e` modifier.

The `e` modifier is now removed/deprecated  - https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

You can simply change the `/e` to `/i` to read this;

```
$read = preg_replace(array('/LANG\[([0-9]*?)\]/i','/URL\[([0-9]*?)\]/i'),array('get_words(\\1)','url(\\1)'),$read);
```

or remove the `e` completely to read this;

```
$read = preg_replace(array('/LANG\[([0-9]*?)\]/','/URL\[([0-9]*?)\]/'),array('get_words(\\1)','url(\\1)'),$read);
```